# error in hive metadata: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using `hive-0.9.0` with `mysql` as a metastore.
I am getting one exception as :

```
hive> show tables;
FAILED: Error in metadata: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException:java.net.SocketTimeoutException:Read timed out

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask 
Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Could not connect to meta store using any of the URIs provided)
```

Any pointers on to would be helpful.

Regards
Neeraj

Comment: Do all the commands you send to hive give you an error? If they do, your connection info may be incorrect.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the metastore directly using the credentials you provide in hive-site.xml and ensured that they are correct?

Answer (score 6):

Did you configure the URL & credential for metastore correctly? Did you try restart your metastore service by

> hive --service metastore

Answer (score 5):

pls check your hive config `${HIVE_HOME}/conf/hive-site.xml`

hive mysql configuration  example:

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>hive</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>hive</value>
</property>
```

Comment: do u miss mysql-connection jar in ${HIVE_HOME}/lib ?

Comment: I don't know why your answer was down-voted, this would have been my first resp too :)

Answer (score 0):

go to hive/hcatalog/sbin

./hcat_server.sh

This should help